# html proofer not finding jekyll collections

Tags: jekyll, travis-ci, html-proofer

Running into a problem where normal pages are working fine, however collection pages are not found by [html-proofer](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer).

Example error message:

```
  *  internally linking to /blog/choose-a-datasource, which does not exist (line 82)
     <a href="/blog/choose-a-datasource" class="current">Choose a data source</a>
```

This message comes from the following Travis report. There are a lot of collection pages not found:
https://travis-ci.org/semi-technologies/semi-website/builds/514826595#L1065

However, when you look in the source folder the the page does exist:
https://github.com/semi-technologies/semi-website/tree/permalinks/_blog

And in a jekyll build these files are successfully created in `./_site`.

Does someone have experience with this?

Comment: What is the desired output here? Do you want urls like `/blog/choose-a-datasource` (same as `/blog/choose-a-datasource.html`) or `/blog/choose-a-datasource/` (same as `/blog/choose-a-datasource/index.html`) ..?

Comment: There's a difference? I think it's configured to use /blog/choose-a-datasource.html. Interesting point, you mean I'd have to remove trailing slashes behind the URL references in order for it to work. I'll try this.

Comment: That solved it.